# NodeJS - How to get image dimensions?

Tags: node.js, image-processing, parse-server

I'm on a `NodeJS server` running `parse server` and I send from my iOS app, the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` of an image, to a `cloud function` call. What I want, is to retrieve the image dimensions, from my cloud function...

I've searched and searched, but without any luck!

Any ideas?

Comment: [You can take a look at this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345903/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-an-image-represented-as-a-unit8array) to achieve your purpose

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size
This lib can calculate the image dimensions:

```
var sizeOf = require('image-size');
sizeOf('images/funny-cats.png', function (err, dimensions) {
  console.log(dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! What I need to do is use the data - `base64` - I already have and get the dimensions... Any idea how to do that?